# Formatting date/time in php 4

Tags: php, string-formatting, datetime-format, php4

I'm working (or learning) on server with old php4 installed and most of the conventional methods from php5 for date/time formatting doesn't work in php4.

I have time string in this format:

```
2003-07-23 10:15:00
```

Now whats the easiest way to get date separately in `23.7.2003` format and then time in `10:15` format?

Comment: I've tryed that, but it allways return date: 01.01.1970

Comment: PHP4 is dead since [long time ago](http://php.net/eol.php). Some of the things you are learning now became deprecated in the meantime. Some others will be deprecated or removed from the language altogether in the near future. Make an effort and install PHP 5 (version 5.4 or newer). You won't regret.

Comment: I would go a step further than @axiac and say:  you're doing yourself a disservice by learning PHP4.  Download WAMP/XAMP and learn PHP5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you ever tried strtotime?

```
print date('d.m.Y H:i', strtotime('2003-07-23 10:15:00'));
```

[Code running on PHP 4](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5d79b1454f28e1aaf6b2eed7bb7cc05070ffb1d6)